# From list of dictionaries to np array of arrays and vice-versa

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, splunk

I am trying to find the best way to transform a list of dictionaries into a numpy array of arrays (filling the missing values with NULL). I also need the opposite way: transform a numpy array of arrays into a list of dictionaries (given a header for the keys).

**The problem:** the Python dictionaries are not ordered. And when dealing with a large number of rows, comprehension lists are not the best option.

**Example:**

```
listOfDicts = [{'key1': 10, 'key2': 15, 'key3': 19},
               {'key1': 20, 'key2': 25, 'key3': 29},
               {'key1': 30, 'key2': 35, 'key3': 39},
               {'key1': 40, 'key2': 45, 'key3': 49}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[[10 15 19]
 [20 25 29]
 [30 35 39]
 [40 45 49]]
```

**Why I need this:** I need this because I am integrating a Python script into a Splunk search. The input from Splunk is a list of dictionaries, returned by `splunk.Intersplunk.getOrganizedResults()`. And to display the output we need to call `splunk.Intersplunk.outputResults(results)` where `results` is also a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
listOfDicts = [{"key1":10, "key3":19},
               {"key1":20, "key2":25, "key3":29},
               {"key1":30, "key2":35, "key3":39},
               {"key1":40, "key2":45, "key3":49}]

df = pd.DataFrame(listOfDicts)
vals = df.values
vals

array([[10, nan, 19],
       [20, 25,  29],
       [30, 35,  39],
       [40, 45,  49]])
```

To convert a NumPy array into a dictionary you can use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=df.columns)
df2.to_dict(orient='records')

[{'key1': 10.0, 'key2': nan, 'key3': 19.0},
 {'key1': 20.0, 'key2': 25.0, 'key3': 29.0},
 {'key1': 30.0, 'key2': 35.0, 'key3': 39.0},
 {'key1': 40.0, 'key2': 45.0, 'key3': 49.0}]
```

Comment: I didn't know pandas can do it. Thanks. And what about the opposite way (array of arrays + header to list of dictionaries) ?

Comment: @belas: Added the opposite way, also with pandas. Pandas can construct DataFrames from many different objects, and once you have a df, converting to a dict is straightforward.